# How to install Pipe Viewer (pv) via microdnf on oraclelinux:8-slim?

Tags: package-management, docker, dnf, oracle-linux

Docker `mysql:8` and `latest` change OS from Debian to `oraclelinux:8-slim`. There is a `microdnf`. So I'm looking for solution to install `pv` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`microdnf` is like `dnf` but does not require Python.

I was able to find the `pv` package in the EPEL repositories which are not enabled by default in the `mysql:8` image available on Docker.  You could conveniently install the `epel-release` package to enable the repository:

```
microdnf install -y epel-release
```

but this seems to pull in the full `dnf` along with Python as dependencies which adds over 200mb to the size of the image.  If that is a concern, you would need to manually create a new repository configuration with the content from the packaged `/etc/yum.repos.d/oracle-epel-ol8.repo`:

```
[ol8_developer_EPEL]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever EPEL Packages for Development ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/developer/EPEL/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1

[ol8_developer_EPEL_modular]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever EPEL Modular Packages for Development ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/developer/EPEL/modular/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Once the EPEL repository is enabled, you can install the `pv` package:

```
microdnf install -y pv
```